# Move object values from objec to array in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

I cannot figure out how to convert objects into a JsonArray.

```
r.db('data').table('user').filter({'_deleted':false}).pluck(['id'])
```

My result looks like this:

```
{
   "id":  "10008590"
}, 
{
   "id":  "10006821"
}
```

And i want it to look like this:

```
[ "10008590", "10006821"]
```

what do i add to a query after `.pluck()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, after the `pluck()` you use the `map()` function to extract the id field:

```
.map(function(doc){return doc('id')})
```

in shorter form:

```
.map(r.row('id'))
```

Note: in the UI i also needed `.coerceTo("array")` to the end

Comment: I am having trouble finding examples / documentation online. Do you happen to know where using `map` in this context is documented? None of the rethinkdb official docs show how things are outputted in their examples.

Comment: True, the official docu doesnt mention this exact use case and do not bother providing sample outputs. But rethinkdb provides the web UI which makes the experiencing pretty quick and easy, i usually do that. Your use case can be achieved with `map`, `concatMap`,  and `do`, you can find some examples and ideas there in the official documentation.